# What's the difference between yellow and orange fire?

Tags: the-binding-of-isaac, wrath-of-the-lamb

With the new DLC I've noticed a new fire animation, that has an "oranger" hue. Is there any difference between this new fire and the old one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The orange fire will, on occasion, *shoot tears at you.* Be ready.

[image: Sneaky orange fire]

Comment: So we can say that... (_puts shades on_) it "fires" back?